# Finding bottlenecks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to find a bottleneck in my Javascript. Basically I'm developing a chrome extension written in Javascript which is taking 4-5 seconds to perform a task. There's a lot of code involved in the task and using print statements / chrome built in dev tools just isnt working. The dev tools don't seem to even see my Javascript running. I'm wondering if anyone has any advice / tools they think could be of benefit?

Comment: We need more information. What task are you performing? Can you give us code listings of the inner loops? Usually, greater performance increases are obtained with better algorithms. Tell us what you're trying to accomplish and how you're trying to accomplish it and maybe we can help more.

Comment: it is a chance that the code isn't running because you uses setTimeout and such. Try to use Timeline to look what really happens.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that an injected content script is very hard to debug and profile because the JS environment is separate from the webpage's and the inspector can't even see the JS script. I don't know any good workarounds yet.

Answer (score 10):

Open your page in Chrome.

Tools -> Developer tools -> Profiles

Start Profiling (3rd button, grey circle on the status bar at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it'd be a good idea to open the HTML files in Firefox instead of letting Chrome extensions handle it.  That'd allow you to use Firebug to determine any causes, which would be very helpful.

Comment: My understanding of Chrome apps is that they're just HTML, CSS and Javascript, so running them in Firefox shouldn't be a problem.  My answer is still the same... I'm not sure what you changed in your original question

Answer (score 0):

I remember Google Chrome has a built-in JavaScript [profiler](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html). Or can't you use this for your extension? (I have never built Chrome extensions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Profiler as it was mentioned before or Timeline.
Timeline will help you if the time was spent in native code.